# React native iOS StatusBar style

Tags: react-native

I have a problem with the iOS status bar style , I define the style to light-content but every time I do a setState in the view the status bar lost his property.

I try to put the status bar on the top of my main container but every time I switch to a different screen the status bar lost his property too.

For navigation I use the Navigator.

Comment: Maybe try setting it in the `index.ios.js` / `index.android.js` file?

Comment: Before I try your solution the status bar lost his properties every times when I change the view and when I do setState on textInput onChangeText callback. So now I put the status bar on index.js. It keep his properties when I change view but not when I change value on textField. This problem happen just on iOS version when I run the android version the status bar don't lost his properties. For both version  I use the simulator.

Comment: I found the solution the problem was I use a special component for the iOS navbar wich include properties for the status bar. So every time I i do setState the navbar override my status bar properties. Sorry ;)